# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '' of object '#<Object>' Redux Tool Kit Slice for Firebase Storage REACT NATIVE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, redux-toolkit

Hello I am trying to set my downloadUrl after uploading to firebase storage and I can't seem to get it to work with Redux Toolkit. I have a solution but I would rather have it the correct way but I cant seem to figure out it would love to get some feed back

Here is the **Documentation** example. I understand that numbers work differently than objects **but if they can change it like this why cant I?**

```
    incrementByAmount: (state, action) => {
  state.value += action.payload
},
```

**And here is my code:**

```
setImageUrl: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
  state.imageUrl = action.payload;
},
```

**And here is where I call it**

```
    const downloadUrl = await FirebaseStorageService.uploadFile(
      photo,
      setUploadProgress
    );

    dispatch(setImageUrl(downloadUrl));
```

Here is the error

```
ossible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 5):
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'imageUrl' of object '#<Object>'
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'imageUrl' of object '#<Object>'
```

Thank you in advance I have seen similar questions on other places but I feel like the answers are not clear. Can I change properties on an object directly or not with RTK?

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it but I don't think it is the right resolution or rather it does not really explain RTK to me coming from `.Net`. I just think it is incorrect:

```
  const downloadUrl = await FirebaseStorageService.uploadFile(
                        photo,
                        setUploadProgress
                      );
  reduxExpense.imageUrl = downloadUrl;
  dispatch(setExpense(reduxExpense));
```

I don't think we need `redux` instead I could just do:

```
expense.ImageUrl = downloadUrl;
```

Or is this a correct implementation? Could someone help? Thanks!